# how is this done with join?

Tags: mysql, sql

Select * from Birey b where Id = (select OgrenciId from SınavOgrenci s where s.Notu=92 )

Comment: huh?  What do you mean?

Comment: do you have a foreign key?

Comment: Better read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Birey INNER JOIN SınavOgrenci ON Birey .Id=SınavOgrenci .Id
WHERE SınavOgrenci.Notu=92
```

you can see other join

see in below link

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: thank you ı m doing now, also thanks for the link

Comment: Just to point out this answer is incorrect. It produces a different result.

Comment: ı looked at the link he threw and ı m tyring other answers

Answer (score -1):

it can be something like this:

```
Select *
from Birey b inner join SınavOgrenci s on b.Id = s.OgrenciId 
where s.Notu=92
```

note: your original query will fail if there are multiple records in SınavOgrenci table

query with join will not fail, but return multiple records instead

Answer (score -1):

Select * 
from Birey b 
inner join SınavOgrenci s
on( b.Id = s.OgrenciId and s.Notu=92 )